# SSD found by Bios but don't boot Windows

Tags: windows, boot, ssd, bios

I have a Samsung 840 SSD who was working well one week ago and booting rapidly on Windows 10.

Then the pump of my watercooling died, so I replaced it yesterday. The liquid from the watercooling didn't touch any component of the PC.

After replacing the pump I replugged every component (MB, GPU, ...) but my Windows 10 didn't boot anymore. I don't even see the blue Windows logo.

There is only two blank screens with white blinking caret then it's going back in the BIOS.

I tried to modify some boot option and see if the SSD is detected by the BIOS without success.

I search Google without success too.

Do you have any ideas ? Is the SSD died ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your situation ,Try below steps:

1. This could be due to Loose Power/SATA cable if SSD is not detecting, interchange powercable & SATA cable for your SSD.
2. Your new cooler might be consuming more power than required, is there anyway you can remove the cooler and try boot up again?
3. Verify Boot Mode if boot mode alreaddy set to legacy change to UEFI and see, if UEFI was set earlier your computer wont boot with Legacy Mode. (Verify with Possible SATA Modes as well RAID/SATA if you dont remember previous configuration).

Comment: I tried changing SATA cable and powercable and I tried to start it without the cooler without success. Changing the boot mode don't work either

Comment: try last  step if you remember which BIOS mode and SATA mode you installed OS? then can try connect that SSD to other system with both these settings modified.  This step just to know atleast your ssd is in working condition..

Comment: I found why windows wasn't booting. I had an Ubuntu install on another HD, but it was unplugged. I replugged it, then I could choose inside grub boot loader for windows, then it booted. Thanks anyway for you help